# Chamar função em PHP via Link utilizando MVC

Tags: php, funções, mvc

Estou com Dificuldade/Problema para realizar requisição a uma função no PHP:

Está função abaixo esta localizada em uma classe dentro da Pasta ***lib***.

**Language.php**

```
<?php

namespace app\lib;

class Language {

    public function setLingCookie(){
        if(isset($linguagem)){
            setcookie("IDIOMA", $linguagem, time()+3600, "/", "localhost/");
            echo 1;
        }else{
            echo 0;
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Minha dificuldade está por acionar esta função pela minha página, sendo que acionarei isso a partir de um Link.


Deixando registrado aqui que já tentei alguma funções por Ajax porém não obtive sucesso porque não estou sabendo tratar a requisição ou não estou sabendo enviar.
**Edit**: Estou usando o *Composer* somente para o *Autoload*.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa de uma página , por exemplo, `setcookie.php`, e nessa página, você deve instanciar a classe que você criou, mais ou menos assim:

```
$l = new Language();
$l->setLingCookie();
```

Está usando algum framework? Dependendo do framework, podem haver meios de acessar essa função por rotas, mas como não mencionou nenhum, o método seria por um arquivo php que instanciasse essa classe que você fez

Espero ter ajudado!!

Comment: Então, estou usando Composer só para o Autoload.
Eu consigo criar um Cookie pelo Js nada complicado mas queria fazer toda estrutura por PHP. Pensei no que me falou passando um parâmetro mas teria que ser um POST neste novo arquivo por meio do Ajax certo? 
Também teria como eu fazer o click no link para essa rota passando um parâmetro e um redirecionamento de volta.
Bem, muito obrigado pelo Auxilio!

Comment: Isso, o caminho seria esse mesmo! De nada!